# Enviar email no Django com Sendgrid

Tags: django, email, envio-de-email, sendgrid

Estou trabalhando com Django 2.2 e preciso configurar o Sendgrid para enviar alguns emails no sistema, encontrei alguns tutoriais e estou tentando seguir, fiz o seguinte:

No arquivo `settings.py` adicionei:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'leilaapsilva'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = [senha do sendgrid]
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USER_TLS = True
```

No views.py de um dos apps:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings


send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'leila**@gmail.com', ['leila***@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Não entendi porque o erro se nem alterei nada no urls.py. Alguém sabe como resolver isso ou pode me explicar uma forma melhor de configurar o Sendgrid?

Comment: por que o voto contra?

Comment: vc esta esquecendo da variavel SENDGRID_API_KEY, olhe na [doc](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/django/) deles

Comment: Aparentemente você editou a sua pergunta e removeu a parte que nos mostraria qual erro está dando... Sem este erro qualquer ajuda seria chute. Seria melhor você [edit] sua pergunta e inserir novamente o erro (se o erro for muito grande você pode deixar só a parte importante)